# Cannot see my university WiFi network and unable to connect to it

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

I live in IIT(BHU), Varanasi, India and we have internet connection through ethernet and WiFi. The WiFi network uses 802.1X security and we have Protected EAP authentication. As per the guidelines provided to us, we do not require a CA certificate, and have to set inner authentication to MSCHAPv2, and PEAP version to Automatic. Anonymous identity, username and password have been provided. However, while I am easily able to connect to ethernet using these settings, the WiFi network does not show up in the WiFi networks' Select Network menu. I am using an HP Pavilion notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the WiFi driver is RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.

Another issue is that other WiFi networks have a significantly lower strength on my PC than my smartphone or when I use Windows 10 on the same PC, in case it is relevant.

What do I need to do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> WiFi network does not show up in the WiFi networks' Select Network menu

Can you see any wifi networks?  If so, are the networks that are seen on the same band (2.4 vs 5 ghz) as your school's network?  A network having "unique" authentication should not hinder you from seeing its presence, only make it a challenge to have a successful connection.

Check to make sure you have good drivers by connecting to something else (something wpa2 psk protected), then work your way up to an enterprise wifi network.

Also check the country setting on your WIFI.  If set to North America, and your university is using channel 12 or 13, you are not going to see it.

Comment: I did try to connect to a WiFi network that works on the 2.4 GHz band and is WPA2 PSK protected and was able to do it. It may be noted that I also use Windows 10 on this laptop (in dual boot) and I can connect to the WiFi without a problem. I also checked the country settings and it was set to global, but even after I set it to IN I am not able to see it.